# How to increase row limit exporting excel in laravel excel

Tags: php, excel, laravel, limit, maatwebsite-excel

I am using maatwebsite Laravel Excel and I want to increase the limit of rows exporting. Now it exports 10k rows but I want to change it to 20k.

Comment: Try this out https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/466#issuecomment-204429445

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with big files, it's better to import the data in big chunks.

You can enable this with `filter('chunk');` To import it into chunks you can use `chunk($size, $callback)` instead of the normal `get()`.

The first parameter is the size of the chunk. The second parameter is a closure which will return the results.

```
Excel::filter('chunk')->load('file.csv')->chunk(250, function($results)
{
        foreach($results as $row)
        {
            // do stuff
        }
});
```

dont forget to set php max execution time to:  `set_time_limit ( int $seconds )`

Comment: you should do this when uploading the file and working with it

Comment: let me change the question, how can I decrease the limit to a certain number? I search items on my website then I want to set a limit on laravelexcel. How can I do that?